How to download Firebase json file on new PC
I previously modified the firebas.json file on my PC and distributed it to hosting.
I want to download the project on a new PC and modify the function.
How do I receive the distributed firebase.json file?
When you do firebase init, only the default firebase.json file is created.

There is no way to get the firebase.json file from Firebase. The file is never stored in Firebase, and only exists on the machine where you create it.
You will either have to copy it yourself from the old machine to the new, or recreate it on the new machine the same way you did initially.
